# Инструмент для перевода HTML страниц на другой язык

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет!
У меня появилась задача перевести часть блоков на странице на английский язык.
К примеру есть такой div блок:

```
<div>
    <h3>Заголовок</h3>

    <ul>
        <li>Текст</li>
        <li>Текст</li>
        <li>Текст</li>
    </ul>

    <p>Текст</p>
    ...
 </div>
```

Нужно взять целиком этот блок, и передать инструменту для перевода. Перевестись должен только текст на русском языке, теги должны игнорироваться т.е. получится следующие:

```
<div>
    <h3>Title</h3>

    <ul>
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>Text</li>
    </ul>

    <p>Text</p>
    ...
 </div>
```

Я пробовал делать перевод через yandex tranlate, но он ломает теги.

Кто знает существует ли подобный инструмент с API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение!
Перевод текста выполняется на стороне сервера через google translate перевода сайтов.
Происходит это так:
1. Я сначала перевожу всю страницу через

```
$enPage = file_get_contents("https://translate.google.ru/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=ru&ie=UTF-8&u=mysite.com/page_test.html");
```

2. Затем DOM манипулятором(к примеру phpQuery) выковыриваю ненужные мне блоки и заменяю их теми же блоками только уже переведенными из $enPage

Answer (score 2):

А это не пробовали? https://support.google.com/translate/answer/2534601?hl=ru
Чтобы перевелся только блок, а не вся страница, то, наверное, можно div на iframe заменить и в нем плагин перевода реализовать

Comment: Не совсем то что нужно, хотелось бы без доп. плагинов это сделать. Но все равно спасибо за подсказку.