# Есть ли способ удобного машинного перевода на другой язык размеченного html-тегами текста?

Tags: html, поиск-программ, перевод

Если точнее, то можно ли как-то добавить в исключение все, что находится в угловых скобках `<>`? Возможно какой-то переводчик позволяет это делать. Яндекс и гугл переводчик рвут теги иногда, добавляя пробел в скобках или апперкейс.

Например, было:

```
<h3>Заголовок</h3>
```

Cтало:

```
 < H3>header</ h3>.
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Инструмент для перевода HTML страниц на другой язык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/572472/%d0%98%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-html-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba)

Comment: Интересное решение, попробую.

Answer (score -1):

Немного не понятно... но насколько я понял, вам, чтобы осуществить перевод текста, нужно избавиться от тэгов? Если это так, то надо парсить на стороне сервера при помощи регулярных выражений.

**UPDATE**

Как вариант можно в проперти запихнуть уже готовый перевод. И на страничку сайта ссылаться на пропертю.

Comment: Нужно чтоы преводчик не обращал вни мания на теги и их атрибуты, и на выходе получался размеченный теми же тегами переведенный текст.

Comment: @Black Fire как вам такой вариант: заменить каждый тег на кодовый символ например: <h1></h1> = @ текст @