# Инструмент для перевода HTML страниц на другой язык с помощью file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Я совсем новичок в программировании, занимаюсь продажами через интернет, поэтому мой вопрос наверняка покажется Вам глупым. Простите!(

Мне нужно перевести 10 одностраничных сайтов на английский, и делать это вручную очень не быстро, поэтому нужно понять как работать с этим PHP. Вычитал у Вас на форуме вот такой способ -
[Инструмент для перевода HTML страниц на другой язык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/572472/%d0%98%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-html-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba)

Я уже прочитал 3 форума на эту тему, создал и HTML и PHP, проверил десяток кодов, но они не работают. Не где нет, как написать Полностью весь код для *.html или *.ru Именно такой PHP c $enPage, Или, что скорее всего, Всё не так!

Будьте любезны растолкуйте, или просто напишите код файла PHP или HTML, и что ещё нужно сделать? Перевод откроется на этой же странице или нужно создать какой-то файл в корне? Спасибо!

Comment: ну тот машинный перевод порадует не каждого))

Comment: Вручную будет быстрее